# Share style between several components and deduplicate it

Tags: angular, optimization, sass

**I have several components with `ViewEncapsulation.None` and some style that should be applied to all of them. Also I want this piece of style to be added to compiled bundle only once.**

I had 2 ideas how to do it, but they both don't fit. Let's look at example with 2 components `my-comp-1.component.scss` and `my-comp-2.component.scss` and common style `my-comp.common.scss` without own angular component.

1. Use scss `@import` statement. It adds code of common script to each component's style and when running the app 2 `style` tags of components (including common style inside of each) are added. This means that copy of common style overrides itself and it's possible to override styles of the first component by shared styles of the second:

   [image: screenshot of 2 styles tags]

   [image: screenshot of overrides]
2. Use multiple files in Angular's `styleUrls` property. Now 3 style tags are added and at least it works correctly. But the problem is that `main.js` bundle actually contains 2 copies of shared style (1 per each component) and deduplication is made in runtime. Is it possible to move this deduplication into compile time to reduce size of the bundle?

   [image: screenshot of 3 styles tags]

   [image: screenshot of correct styles applied]

   [image: screenshot of the first component in the bundle]

   [image: screenshot of the second component in the bundle]

---

Now a bit more code to reproduce the problem.

- app is created by `ng new` command with scss selected
- for screenshots code is compiled via `npm run build`, but production version has the same structure of bundles

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyComp1Component } from './my-comp-1.component';
import { MyComp2Component } from './my-comp-2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComp1Component,
    MyComp2Component,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <my-comp-1></my-comp-1>
    <my-comp-2></my-comp-2>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-test';
}
```

my-comp-1.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp-1',
  template: `
    <p class="my-comp my-comp-1">My first component</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./my-comp.common.scss', './my-comp-1.component.scss'],
  // styleUrls: ['./my-comp-1.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MyComp1Component {
  title = 'angular-test';
}
```

my-comp-1.component.scss

```
// @import 'my-comp.common.scss';

.my-comp-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

my-comp-2.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp-2',
  template: `
    <p class="my-comp my-comp-2">My second component</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./my-comp.common.scss', './my-comp-2.component.scss'],
  // styleUrls: ['./my-comp-2.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MyComp2Component {
  title = 'angular-test';
}
```

my-comp-2.component.scss

```
// @import 'my-comp.common.scss';

.my-comp-2 {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

my-comp.common.scss

```
.my-comp {
  color: blue;
}
```

Full screenshot with scss `@import`:

[image: Full screenshot with scss @import]

Full screenshot with angular `styleUrls`:

[image: Full screenshot with angular styleUrls]

Answer (score 0):

You can import the styles in the style.scss in the src folder of the project so that it will not be duplicated while mounting the component and also in the bundle.

Comment: But than it would be global style that is always added to the page. I wanted styles to have relation to the components so that if these components are not used (maybe for lazy loading reasons), these styles are not loaded to the client.

Comment: That is not yet possible with angular.

Answer (score -1):

use ViewEncapsulation in your typescript component to share the styles:

```
@Component({
  selector: "toolbar",
  templateUrl: "./sth.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./sth.component.scss"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Comment: Already using it. It's not a thing I'm asking about.